# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, ... when running unit tests

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2012, ado.net, mstest

I'm trying to run some unit tests that perform execute some SQL commands directly to an Oracle database and I get the following exception when the unit tests are started:

> Testmethod1 threw exception:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have `Oracle.DataAccess` in the project references (added through NuGet) and I have I have the Oracle Data Provider installed.

I even have some other projects using `Oracle.DataAccess` that run in this machine without problems. It seems that only Microsoft.Net Unit Test Framework (MSTest) is not able to load the assembly.

This is the log taken from Fusion Log Viewer:

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (23/08/2013 @ 04:50:07 p.m.) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\QTAgent32_40.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ...
LOG: DisplayName = Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///...C:/<solution_folder>.../TestResults/.../Out
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = QTAgent32_40.exe
Calling assembly : ...<project_name>..., Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\...<solution_folder>...\TestResults\...\Out\...<project_name>....DLL.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/...<solution_folder>.../TestResults/.../Out/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/...<solution_folder>.../TestResults/.../Out/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/...<solution_folder>.../TestResults/.../Out/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/...<solution_folder>.../TestResults/.../Out/Oracle.DataAccess/Oracle.DataAccess.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

It states the assembly was not found in the GAC, but I did found it: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\Oracle.DataAccess.dll\`

It's also worth noting is that the above log shows `QTAgent32_40.exe` even though I have selected in Visual Studio menu `TEST -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> X64`. Before doing so I was getting a `BadImageFormatException` instead.

**Additional notes:**

- The Oracle Data Provider that I have installed is the 64 bit version.
- The reference already has `Copy Local=True`

Comment: Turn on fusion logging to see if that helps you figure out what file is missing: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=3654c8f3-c5c3-4dee-a01f-c9a8da3ef2fa

Comment: Didn't know about it. Thanks. I just added it to the question

Comment: Are your tests running as a 32 bit process?

Comment: Nope, 64 bit and the Oracle Data Provider installed and referenced from the project is the 64 version... Otherwise I would get a BadImageFormatException instead (been there)

Comment: A quick fix would be to set `CopyLocal` to true on the reference, but it should work from the GAC.

Comment: The reference already has `CopyLocal = True`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem.

**There was a .testsettings file forcing the tests to be run in 32 bit mode** regardless of me selecting `TEST -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> X64`.

The weird thing is that if I select X86 I get the proper `BadImageFormatException` at runtime, while if the architecture is forced in the .testsettings file I get `FileNotFoundException`, which is a little misleading.

Comment: I was experiencing this same problem and used your response to point me in the right direction. I didn't find a .testsettings file in VS 2017 Professional, but I found this answer on another similar StackOverflow question. Go to Test -> Test Settings \\\ Uncheck the \..\..projectTestSettings.testsettings file \\\ Run the tests again.  I did not see anything in this test settings file that would indicate X86 execution, but it worked to fix the error of FileNotFoundException.